# String Converting Issue

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

Ive been stunk in working with java and mysql these days. 
The problem is, ive got a mysql database. There is a column in one table which shows the chinese city names. One collegue changed the db to utf8 for every character(connection, db, results, server and system) The consequence is that the data before the change didn't show correctly any more only if i set the %character% back to latin1. In either character set i can only retrive half the data correctly. Could you please help me how to solve the problem? 
Ive tried to use java to solve the problem but it doesn't work.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_addresses";
ResultSet result = query.executeQuery(sql);
while (result.next()) {
    byte b[] = result.getBytes("city");
    c = new String(result.getBytes("city"), "UTF-8");
}

For example: there is one city in db like this ä¹Œé²æœ¨é½å¸‚
the java print:  乌�?木�?市
it should be:乌鲁木齐市
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is not very clear. Does everything work if EVERYTHING is set to UTF-8? I would expect so

Comment: thanks for answering as said the earilier data are encoded with latin1 and the later using utf8

Comment: so UTF-8 encoded data was added to ISO-8859-1 data? That's foolish, I would say

Comment: if this is what happened, the only way out is to use some other information (like a date) to distinguish the two encodings, use a single-byte connection, if possible without any conversion (I don't remember how to set up that, but it should be possible, it MIGHT be possible with latin1), and then convert the older data with Java or whatever programming language you have

Comment: well so it is and i have to deal with it

Comment: remember that there is no safe way to tell by the strings themselves whether the encoding is latin1 or utf8 (ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8)

Comment: do you mean what i also thought before like pull out all the old data and then change encoding and store them back?

Comment: yes, I would to that, but keeping a backup of the old data, and with a clear way to tell bad old from good old from new

Comment: well thats gonna be it thanks walter

Comment: anyway, your data seems corrupted, since you showed us a 12 byte long latin1 string, which, at 3 bytes per chinese glyph (in utf8), would be 4 chinese glyphs, whereas you expect 5. Or else, it's the connection that doesn't let some characters through - which would probably mean that latin1 is not sufficient to let everything through. Which might make an in-DB conversion preferrable

Comment: i think the connection is fine because im testing locally. There is a xml backup file somewhere. i am up to deal the old data from there.

Comment: no, the connection is not fine, I just checked: the missing bytes have values 0x81, 0x90 and 0x82. They are not defined in latin1

Comment: im now confused. what possible reason could it be that my localhost prevents the data through. My firewall?

Comment: not the firewall, but at the same time I'm not so sure that the problem is the connection rather than Java (so, take my previous "no" with caution). Anyway, I looked it up: the "binary" charset should be the one that lets everything through.

Comment: you helped me alot walter thanks so much lol

Comment: not really... and furthermore: I found out now that latin1 is not ISO-8859-1, but essentially Windows codepage 1252, where at least part of those bytes are defined... Anyway, they are problematic for something down the line, which doesn't surprise me. I'm not sure your situation is the one that is solved by the second part of @Joni's answer, but you could in any case consider converting only PART of your data (e.g., by copying that part to a temporary table). Your target is a database where all charset parameters, everywhere, are utf8(_something) (e.g., utf8_bin)

Comment: exectly. the solution by joni doesn't work and i solved it by using a temp table. Thanks for the help walter, i mean it

Answer (score 0):

Default charset of your MySQL server is probably not UTF8. Try to execute the following SQL queries before getting data from the database:

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

and

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: ive changed every variables like '%character%' to utf8

Answer (score 0):

Add `characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the *connection string*, where you connect to the database. For example:

```
"jdbc:mysql://servername:3306/databasename?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Incidentally, the data in the database appears to be broken. If you want the database to store 乌鲁木齐市, that's what should be in the table, not ä¹Œé²æœ¨é½å¸.

**Update:** The problem with the how the data is stored in the database is easier to solve using database's own tools, not Java. For each table that stores text do this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET binary;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: thanks joni you may misundstand me.  I want to update a existing data like ä¹Œé²æœ¨é½å¸‚ to 乌鲁木齐市 using java. btw, ive tried the tipp you gave me and it still doesn't show correctly.

Comment: That problem is easier to solve using database's own tools: `ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET binary` followed by `ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8`

Comment: tried your tipp. either set the character set to utf8 or latin1 return with half of the data correctly. The other half remains like ä¹Œé²æœ¨é½å¸